# Using different fillStyles in the same string?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm wondering if there is a way to do 2 different `fillStyle`'s in the same `fillText` on canvas.

Example: If I have a string `var string = "text";`.

How could i then write that string in different colors with `fillText(string, X, Y)`.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to split the string into its specific coloured parts, and render each part separately, though position them together to appear as if they were rendered using one `fillText()` call.

In order to properly position your multiple text rendering, you can use [`measureText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas#measureText%28%29) to assist you.

Comment: How could I do this? all i got so far is a for loop with charAt(i).